# Unexpected exception after running Azure functions on some requests

Tags: azure-functions

I've deployed some Azure functions and things seems to be working, but the telemetry of AppInsights shows that sometimes there are some SocketException raised after the functions have been executed. Not just at the moment the function ends, but some time after that, maybe 3 minutes, maybe 20.

These errors don't happen everytime, many executions are totally right, while others generate these exceptions and sometimes not just once, but 2 or more times after the execution.

The functions are written in C# and connect to an Azure SQL Database to query/update the data. As the error don't happen every time I don't have a clue about how I can try to debug and fix whatever I might need to fix in order to prevent the exception. 
Also, this comes from the production server, so I can't tweak things lightly.

Can anyone shed some light on the problem? 
What can I do to prevent the exceptions?

This is for example the time graph of one such call:
[image]

And these are the details of all the telemetry of the call
[image]

Exception details:
[image]

Finally, this is the callstack:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__40.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__39.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Se identificó la excepción interna System.IO.IOException en System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+<<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|38_0>d`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__34`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Se identificó la excepción interna System.Net.Sockets.SocketException en System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException:
```

Comment: That's a timeout error.  Some data didn't make it.  Is the database busy?  The real question is, why are these connections still open after the function completes.   Can you share your function signature?  When you call out is it async?  Are you using HttpClient?

Comment: I don't think that the database has too much load, it has some spikes due to a synchronization task (that it's planned to be removed after finishing migrating everything). This is the function signature: `public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)`. We don't use HttpClient or any other custom calls, only SqlClient. I've noticed that we didn't clear the ILogger property, we'll adjust it for the next release on Monday.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe check to make sure all connections are disposed.  When you use the SqlConnections are they wrapped in a `using{}` block? If not is it possible they are left open after the function completes. Or do we ever explicitly close them with `SqlConnection.close()`

Comment: The SqlConnections are wrapped in an utility class and all the instances of that are disposed by `using{}`.

Comment: Just circling back.  Is this fixed?  Thinking on it, this really does feel like you might be calling out to the database in an async fashion (leaving connections open even though the function looks complete) and the database is sometimes overloaded and one of your transactions either timesout - or more likely - because it happens anywhere between 3m and 20m after execution... that your transaction was selected as a deadlock victim and the remote sql server closed the connection.  That would bubble up an error just like they one you see. Can the DBA check for historical deadlocks? sp_BlitzLoc

Comment: No, it's not fixed, those exceptions are still being logged. I don't think that the DB is overloaded as the usage shows a maximum peak of 49%. I've tried to find that sp_BlitzLoc but there are no references about it. The Database is a SQL Server in the same Resource group and location

Comment: You don't need to be at 100% usage to get a deadlock.  sp_BlitzLoc is something you'd have to add to the production SQL server.  It would help to rule out deadlocks as a possible root cause. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/